# Docker - drone.io drone-agent installation getting errors

Tags: drone.io

I am new to Drone ci/cd while installing getting the below issues 
and I am stuck at starting point. See below the installation steps I followed....

I've installed docker and docker compose. Below is the docker file which I used to configure cat docker-compose.yml version: '3'.

All this is configured at my Oracle VM Virtual Box.

```
services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8000:8000
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/drone:/var/lib/drone
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - /etc/drone-ci/server.env

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    command: agent
    depends_on:
      - drone-server
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - /etc/drone-ci/agent.env

    Drone agent.env config file
DRONE_SECRET=5Kt8P0I4uLuzdVTEpC4TxzwineaM8EBxrIZVXriENxNiXvPnsoWm9AMD4Slfybbof
DRONE_SERVER=ws://192.168.200.180/ws/broker

server.env  

DRONE_SECRET=5Kt8P0I4uLuzdVTEpC4TxzwineaM8EBxrIZVXriENxNiXvPnsoWm9AMD4Slfybbof
DRONE_HOST=http://192.168.200.180
DRONE_OPEN=true
DRONE_GITHUB=true
DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=93fc7a0e4f098b289de8
DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=e2ce2dbbdd10d6166ffd6eac99b6818a33d53d8d
DRONE_ADMIN=sravan1265

##########################################################################

While i ran this got the below output:

    docker-compose up
    Recreating root_drone-server_1 ... done
    Recreating root_drone-agent_1 ... done
    Attaching to root_drone-server_1, root_drone-agent_1
    drone-server_1  | time="2018-03-07T11:49:41Z" level=warning msg="agents can connect with token 
    eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0ZXh0IjoiNUt0OFAwSTR1THV6ZFZURXBDNFR4endpbmVhTThFQnhySVpWWHJpRU54TmlYdlBuc29XbTlBTUQ0U2xmeWJib2YiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWdlbnQifQ.nOOmxh7yttAAyq_NiDc182ZQKbQXWCYo8bbgIJ-0h20"
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
    drone-server_1  |  - using env: export GIN_MODE=release
    drone-server_1  |  - using code:        gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    drone-server_1  |

    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/user/token           --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostToken (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] DELETE /api/user/token           --> github.com/drone/drone/server.DeleteToken (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/users                --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetUsers (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/users                --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostUser (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/users/:login         --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetUser (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] PATCH  /api/users/:login         --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PatchUser (16 handlers)


    github.com/drone/drone/server.PostTeamSecret (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] DELETE /api/teams/:team/secrets/:secret --> github.com/drone/drone/server.DeleteTeamSecret (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/global/secrets       --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetGlobalSecrets (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/global/secrets       --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostGlobalSecret (16 handlers)

    ...................................../api/repos/:owner/:name/builds/:number --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetBuild (18 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/repos/:owner/:name/logs/:number/:job --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetBuildLogs (18 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/repos/:owner/:name/sign --> github.com/drone/drone/server.Sign (19 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/repos/:owner/:name/secrets --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetSecrets (19 handlers)

    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/repos/:owner/:name/builds/:number --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostBuild (19 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] DELETE /api/repos/:owner/:name/builds/:number/:job --> github.com/drone/drone/server.DeleteBuild (19 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/badges/:owner/:name/status.svg --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetBadge (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/badges/:owner/:name/cc.xml --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetCC (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /hook                     --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostHook (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/hook                 --> github.com/drone/drone/server.PostHook (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /ws/broker                --> github.com/drone/drone/server.Broker (15 handlers)


    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /ws/feed                  --> github.com/drone/drone/server.EventStream (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /ws/logs/:owner/:name/:build/:number --> github.com/drone/drone/server.LogStream (18 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /authorize                --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetLogin (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /authorize                --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetLogin (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /authorize/token          --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetLoginToken (15 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/builds               --> github.com/drone/drone/server.GetBuildQueue (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/debug/pprof/         --> github.com/drone/drone/server/debug.IndexHandler.func1 (16 handlers)
    drone-server_1  | [GIN-debug] GET    /api/debug/pprof/heap     --> 


    drone-agent_1   | 1:M 07 Mar 11:49:41.579 * connecting to server ws://192.168.200.180/ws/broker

    drone-agent_1   | 1:M 07 Mar 11:49:41.580 # connection failed, retry in 15s. websocket.Dial ws://192.168.200.180/ws/broker: dial tcp 192.168.200.180:80: getsockopt: connection refused
    drone-agent_1   | 1:M 07 Mar 11:49:56.580 # connection failed, retry in 15s. websocket.Dial ws://192.168.200.180/ws/broker: dial tcp 192.168.200.180:80: getsockopt: connection refused
    drone-agent_1   | 1:M 07 Mar 11:50:11.582 # connection failed, retry in 15s. websocket.Dial ws://192.168.200.180/ws/broker: dial tcp 1`enter code here`92.168.200.180:80: getsockopt: connection refused.
```

Comment: sravan... I've done some serious patchwork on your question layout. Please take a minute once/if my edit is approved how to do it in the future. There is more needed to get you flying again like telling us which script you work with, your OS + build version, how you did your install and more but that's for the experts.

Comment: Why do you give your credentials ?

Comment: I do not suppose to give credentials

Comment: Any help on this issue

Comment: I just noticed you are running drone:0.5, which is deprecated. Have you considered starting with the latest version (0.8 as of writing this comment). http://docs.drone.io/installation/